# Significance of the graph represented by the inverse of the adjacency matrix of another graph

Tags: graph-theory

I think I should first say that I don't know anything about graph theory outside of what an adjacency matrix is and the fact that it can be used to find paths of a given length.

Suppose the adjacency matrix $M$ of an undirected graph $G$ is invertible. It appears the nonzero entries of $M^{-1}$ are then all $\pm 1$. (This has turned out to be the case for the few $3$-vertex graphs that I tried this with in school.)

How is the graph $G'$ represented by $M^{-1}$ (with all the $-1$s changed to $1$s) related to $G$? Do the $-1$s have any significance?

I'm writing $1$s on the diagonal for loops, although if there is an interesting answer using the convention of writing $2$s, I'm all ears.

Comment: This is not true that the entries are all $\pm1$ (I just tried for $K_{3}$ and they were all $\pm .5$. Also the Peterson graph adjacency matrix inverse has $0$, $1/3$, $-2/3$ as entries).  Some adjacency matrices aren't even invertible.  So really this question does not make any sense.

Comment: I mostly agree with @Morgan Rodgers, but you might give this a try: http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/spma.2013.1.issue/spma-2013-0006/spma-2013-0006.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not you can say anything useful in general. For trees (and forests), if the inverse exists then it is a $0,\pm1$ matrix, and is diagonally similar to a 01-matrix. For an on-line paper, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.2177.pdf